# Etliche: several or few or some?

Tags: indefinite-pronoun

*Etliche* can mean few and also several (a lot), but how?

Somewhere I have read that:

> - etliche:
>
>   1. if adj: always means "a lot"
>   2. if noun:
>
>      - 2a) (plural): means few
>      - 2b) (singular): means "a lot"

What a bout "some"? When does it mean "some" ?

Comment: I am amazed again and again at how much nonsense is distributed. Neither is _etliche_ an adjective nor is it a noun. It is an indefinite pronoun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *»etliche«* is neither an adjective, nor a noun. Wherever you've read this: Take this book and throw it away. There is only nonsense in it. If it was a website: Delete it from your bookmarks.

*»Etliche«* is an indefinite pronoun. This is a kind of pronouns, and pronouns are a distinct part of speech, different from verbs, adjectives, nouns, etc.

And *»etliche«* never means *few*. It always means *some, several* or *a lot (of)*.

Here are representative examples (taken from [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/etlich)):

> **Etliche** Male hielt der Bus bis wir ausstiegen.
>   The bus stopped **several** times until we got out.
>
> Es war schon 12 Uhr, aber **etliche** Leute kamen zu spät.
>   It was already 12 o'clock, but **some** people came too late.
>
> Wir haben schon **etliche** lange Gesundheitsreformen hinter uns.
>   We have already gone through **a lot of** long health care reforms.
>
> Wir sind beim Renovieren der Wohnung, aber **etliches** ist noch zu machen.
>   We are renovating the apartment, but there are still **some things** to do.
>
> Neben Brot, Butter und Käse stand noch **etliches** anderes auf dem Einkaufszettel.
>   In addition to bread, butter and cheese there was still **a lot** else on the shopping list.

Comment: The bus stopped **a few** times until we got out. It was already 12 o'clock but quite **a few** people came too late. We've already gone through quite **a few** lengthy health care reforms. We are refurbishing the apartment but there are still **a few** things to do. - *Es fehlt mir zudem auch ein Hinweis auf die bildungssprachliche, umgangssprachliche oder veraltete Verwendung von **etliche***. Siehe https://www.dwds.de/wb/etliche für weitere Anregungen.

Comment: @Takkat **a few** is not **few**. They mean quite the opposite of each other.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: und was soll er OP jetzt daraus lernen? Willst Du ihm weismachen, dass `etliche` nicht mit `a few` übersetzt werden soll, oder was? Ich verstehe Deinen Kommentar hier nicht.

Comment: @Takkat, wie kommst du darauf? Ich hatte eher die Vermutung, dass du den Unterschied zwischen _few_ und _a few_ nicht kanntest. Denn durch den Fettdruck scheint das so, als hättest du Hubert darauf hinweisen wollen, dass _etliche_ eben doch etwas mit _few_ (worum es dem OP ja schließlich geht) zu tun hätte. Hat es jedoch nicht, sehr wohl aber mit _a few_ (worum es dem OP offensichtlich nicht geht).

Comment: @Takkat: Was hindert dich daran, eine bessere Antwort zu schreiben? Nörgeln und andere schlecht machen kann jeder. Versuche stattdessen lieber, es selber besser zu machen.